# UserFrom1の変数をUserFromフォーム2に受け渡す方法

Tags: vba

UserFrom1のCommandButton1をクリックした際に、変数Aに10を代入。（変数Aはパブリック変数）その後UserFrom2.Showで、UserFrom2を表示させ、UserFrom2のMsgBoxに、変数Aの内容を表示させるにはどの様なコードになりますでしょうか？

現在、UserFrom2内のプログラムで、MsgBox UserFrom1.Aとしていますが、10が表示されません。

Comment: 実際にUserFrom1.Aには10がセットされていますか？ただしくUserForm1.Aが定義されていて値が入っていれば、とりあえずそれで表示されるはずです

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。代入は問題ありません。Userfrom1のなかで、MsgBoxでAの内容は表示出来ました。しかし、Userfrom2で、代入されている変数Aを呼び出すと変数Aの中が空になってしまいます。

Comment: パラパラと文章で受け答えするよりもこの記事 [【VBA】フォーム(画面)間でデータの受け渡しをする](https://excel-toshokan.com/vba-tec-formdata/) のように具体的なソースコードを提示した方が良いと思われます。「問題ありません」とした所やそれ以外でも誤解や見落としが存在するのかもしれません。実際に表示がされないという問題が発生している訳ですから。

Answer (score 0):

UserFrom2を呼び出すタイミングなどが分からないのですが、
こちらのコードで試すとUserFrom2のボタンを押すとUserFrom1.Aに収めた値が表示されました。

UserFrom1

```
Option Explicit
Public A As String
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    A = 10
    UserFrom2.Show
End Sub
```

UserFrom2

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox UserFrom1.A
End Sub
```

Comment: 本日試した所、MsgBox UserFrom1.Aでデータを取り出すことができました！原因につきましては、UserFrom2を開いたあと、UserFrom1をUnlodeしていたため、変数が初期化されていました。Unlodeではなく、Hideにすると受け渡しできました。回答して頂きました方々、本当にありがとうございます。そしてお騒がせしました。